# How to extract an array from a List of anonymous objects

Tags: c#, linq

Could anyone please help with the following:

If I have a list declared as follows:

```
List<(uint u, string s)> list1 = new List<(uint u, string s)>();
```

Is there a succinct LINQ statement that could extract a list of the uints in my list?

For example, if my list was initialised as:

```
list1.Add((1,"One"));
list1.Add((2,"Two"));
list1.Add((3,"Three"));
```

How could I crate a List containing the numbers {1,2,3}

At the moment I create an array of uints an loop through the array, but how could this be done using LINQ?

Thanks for any help,
Mitch.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `Select` for projection and `ToList` to accumulate to a list.

```
var result = list1.Select(x => x.u).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks very much for such a quick response. Works perfectly.